# Generic term for needle gauge

Tags: synonyms

Is there a generic term for a "needle gauge", examples being tachometers, speedometers.

Example picture

[image]

This is specifically a tachometer which measures RPM, but I'm looking for a word/words that indicate that it is a device which has a needle rotating around the center point, indicating some value being measured on the outside of the circle.

Comment: Note that "needle gauge" most commonly refers to the size of a hypodermic needle.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what google turned up for me, which led me to post this question.

Comment: I think a key missing word is "analog" which would distinguish such a device from the now-common digital meters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of these is a kind of ***meter***. Your examples tachometers, speedometer give that away.
They are commonly called gauges whether or not they are radial or round.

Comment: So if I wanted to describe this specific object, would it be correct to say a radial meter, to differentiate it from other types of meters? Or radial guage?

Comment: Radial to distinguish from horizontal or vertical gauges. Since the units are in RPMs, rotations per minute I would call it an accelerometer [sp] but more commonly known as a tachometer.